# SharePoint scope display groups

Tags: search, scopedisplaygroup

Is it possible to show multiple display groups in SharePoint search instead of scope dropdown. How to customize the search result page? i need to change the result page in which if i click on the result link corresponding description should be displayed at the bottom of the result page. For that i need to know in which format the result will be returned..

Comment: can u explain what do you mean by result format?

Comment: Format in which xml data will be returned.. will it be same for all search results or it may vary for list, documents, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple display groups by going to Site Actions -> Site settings -> Search Scopes under Site collection settings.

Now, if you have added multiple display groups, you can configure each of those display group for each of your search center in your sites or subsites. Basically if you edit the results.aspx page in the search center, you can edit the scopes drop down web part, where you can see an option to enter the scope display group name. This will enable you to select any of the scope display groups that you have already created.

Comment: Can a single search page have three diplay groups displayed?

Comment: A single search page just has one search drop down and each search drop down can accomodate only one display group. If you need multiple display groups, then you ought to have multiple search centers in each of your sub sites, where each search center will have one display group.

Comment: Now i have a scenario that i have to use search option in my page where there are many filters used like category, type, etc.. in a drop down box and also search box..when i enter search query and click search button my search results should be depend on these filters also..i thought of using scope display group for each filter..is there any other solution available where i want to use existing search option in sharepoint rather creating custom one..

Comment: Refer this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185660.aspx

Comment: Here they stated it is possible to assign different display groups to single search page..

Comment: I believe it speaks about different display groups for a search page and an advanced search page. These are literally 2 different pages with the search box in both the pages. Hence you will be able to have different groups in different pages. As I had explained above, if you have multiple search centers or pages or search boxes in a single page which is highly unlikely, then you can have different display groups. Scope display group is a property of a search box and you cannot have multiple values for a property. Please correct me if I have missed something else.